# Algolia keeps casting tmy data to a string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, algolia

I have been succesful in uploading my data to algolia using laravel. My create method looks like this:

```
Beer::firstOrCreate([
    'name' => $beer['title'],
    'description' => $beer['description'],
    'path' => '/uploads/gall/' . $filename,
    'brewery_id' => '',
    'abv' => $abv
]);
```

It gathers data from an api and works perfectly, except for the abv value. It needs to be a numeric type in algolia but whenever I check it in algolia it is a string.

Even when I force it to a float or int by using:

```
(float)$abv
```

I still end up with a string in my Algolia database. Funny enough the primary id for this record that is being auto incremented is not a string and looks fine in the algolia database.

To implement algolia in laravel I used the laravel helper in my model:

```
// Send new records to the algolia database
use AlgoliaEloquentTrait;
```

I hope somebody can maybe give me slight hint of what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the data type of 'abv' inside your database is **float and not string**, if this is the case then try using `floatval($abv)`. Your code would be something like:

```
Beer::firstOrCreate([
    'name' => $beer['title'],
    'description' => $beer['description'],
    'path' => '/uploads/gall/' . $filename,
    'brewery_id' => '',
    'abv' => floatval($abv)
]);
```

Cheers,,

Comment: I checked my value and it seems to be cast to a string somewhere in my code because I checked it with gettype. I just casted the $abv value to a float value now but I still have to check where it goes wrong. Thanks for taking a look though!